# Exchanging type parameters with abstract types

Tags: scala

To avoid having to repeat type parameter information when subclassing parameterized classes, I'm trying to rewrite some code to use abstract types instead.

What I'd like to express is similar to:

```
class Group[A]

abstract class Thing[A, G <: Group[A]] {
  val group: G
}

class SomeGroup[A] extends Group[A] { g =>    
  object SomeThing extends Thing[A, SomeGroup[A]] {
    val group = g
  }
}
```

Using abstract types, my best attempt so far is:

```
class Group {
  type A
}

abstract class Thing { t =>
  type A
  type G <: Group { type A = t.A }
  val group: G
}

class SomeGroup extends Group { g =>
  object SomeThing extends Thing {
    type A = g.A
    type G = SomeGroup { type A = g.A }
    val group = g
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting a compiler error on the last line saying "value group has incompatible type".

*How can I write the first example using abstract types?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the type checker/inferrer a little help:

```
val group : G = g
```

makes it go through.

Comment: That was simpler than I thought. :) Any good reasons why this is necessary here?

Comment: I would imagine that without any help, the type-checker sees the type of `g` to be just `SomeGroup`, and unless you use a type annotation, that's the type that gets assigned to `group`. Don't take my word for it, though.